# Reload an Activity in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, reload, lifecycle

I have a List View in a page and inside the ListView on click on a button I want to reload the page with new set of data on it.

```
package com.examples.listzones;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView list = new ListView(this);
    setContentView(list);

    String[] items = { "Tom", "Sally", "Bill", "John", "Santiago", "Isabella" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.review, R.id.textView1, items) {
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View text = row.findViewById(R.id.seemore);
        text.setTag(position);
        text.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);

        return row;
      }
    };

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.seemore:

      // RELOAD THE PAGE WITH NEW SET OF DATA

      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Click " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Inside OnClick I want to load the page with new dataset.

Comment: I would not recommend reloading your complete activity. See my answer below. Although batteries are getting better and the devices becomming more powerful you are still developing on a mobile system where you - as a developer - have somehow a responsibility to save resources :) So if you just need to update the data it will be more efficient to not reload everything since a lot of other things will happen when you reload the complete activity... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to restart the Activity. You can put the new data into the adapter and notify the adapter, that the dataset has been changed.

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll("new 1"," new 2","new 3");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in onCreate()

```
Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
```

Write below code where you want to restart the activity

```
startActivity(thisIntent); 
finish();
```

Comment: `finish()` will not be ever called in this case, will it?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the adapter when you press the button. don't forget to call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter afterwards. You can also replace the current adapter with a new one

Don't think in pages like this in android

Answer (score 0):

You can move the initialization stuff from your onCreate()-method to a dedicated method, e.g. init() which you can then just call from your onItemClick().

Alternatively you can use the notifyDataSetChanged()-method of your ListView adapter.